# Explain this race condition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Four threads loop for 10 million times each. On each loop they push a number if the list is empty else they pop a number from the list.

```
list = []

threads = []

4.times do |i|
  threads << Thread.new do
    1e7.to_i.times do |i|
      if list.empty?
        list << i
      else
        list.pop
      end
    end
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
p list
```

Since the loop executes an even number of times, I would expect the list to be empty after all the threads execute.

However, sometimes the list contains the number 9999999.

I thought that Array in MRI Ruby is thread safe because of the GIL.

How does the race condition happen in spite of the GIL?

Answer (score 2):

Having only one thread executed at the time does not mean that a thread always stops at a useful line for example at the end of a block before the next thread gets its execution-time.

In your example, it is possible that one thread reads and evaluates `list.empty?` and then has to wait for another thread. The other thread reads and evaluates `list.empty?` too and gets the same result as the first thread. After that, both threads will execute the same branch of the `if` condition because they saw the same state.